# Actions.refresh in react router flux navigation in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using

```
"react-native": "0.48.3",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.21"
```

Is there any possibility to hide navbar and tabbar depending on state?

What I do now is as follows:

```
<Scene key="scene_condition"
                   tabs={true}
                   type="reset"
                   tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}
                   tabBarSelectedItemStyle={styles.tabBarSelectedItemStyle}
                   navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                   titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}
                   lazy={true}
                   hideTabBar={false}
                   hideNavBar={true}
                   tabBarPosition="bottom"
                   labelStyle={{fontSize: 7}}
                   title=""
                   animationEnabled={false}
                   swipeEnabled={false}
                   showLabel={false}>                
                <Scene key="scene_condition_picture"
                       tabBarLabel={gettext("Pictures")}
                       title={gettext("Pictures")}
                       component={CarPicture}
                       type="reset"
                       icon={TabIcon}
                       iconTittleHidden
                       iconName="photo-camera"
                       leftButtonIconStyle={styles.moduleButton}
                       leftButtonImage={require('./img/icons/left.png')}
                       onLeft={(props) => requestOverview(props.request.id)}
                       navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                       titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}/>
                <Scene key="scene_condition_damages"
                       tabBarLabel={gettext("Damages")}
                       title={gettext("Damages")}
                       component={Damages}
                       type="reset"
                       icon={TabIcon}
                       iconTittleHidden
                       iconName="broken-image"
                       leftButtonIconStyle={styles.moduleButton}
                       leftButtonImage={require('./img/icons/left.png')}
                       onLeft={(props) => requestOverview(props.request.id)}
                       navigationBarStyle={styles.navBarStyle}
                       titleStyle={styles.navBarTitleStyle}/>
            </Scene>
```

Thus, this is the main router component and there I have two tab components. In the component **scene_condition_picture** I want to show navBar and tabBar depending on state. Thus, my code is something as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {            
            showCamera: false
        };
    }
```

and then in the `render`method something like this:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.showCamera){
            return <CameraApp cameraData={this.state.data} hideCamera={this.hideCamera.bind(this)} navData={this.props}/>;
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({showCamera: true})}><Text>Show camaer</Text></TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
}
```

I want to hide `navBar` and `tabBar` if the `CameraApp` component is shown. Thus I tried with `Actions.refresh` inside the `componentDidMount` in the CameraApp as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
        Actions.refresh({hideNavBar: true, hideTabBar: true});
}
```

But it doesn't work.

If I log the props in the `scene_condition_picture` component I see that those props are fine (`hideNavBar: true, hideTabBar: true`) but they are not hided.

[image: screen shot 2017-10-09 at 09 45 11]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now with version 4.0.0-beta.28 and above